# What phosphorylates tau protein & and what causes tau to be phosphorylated?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, molecular-biology, neuroscience, neurology

I want to know what phosphorylates tau protein and its 6 isoforms.
I know kinases cause phosphorylation events, and in tau it can be phosphorylated in a healthy neuron in the trans conformation, but when it is hyperphosphorylated it becomes the cis conformation of tau.

Do the same or different kinases cause the normal phosphorylation / abnormal hyperphosphorylation of tau? Is it completed by a single kinase or multiple kinases?

----Edit---

So I've done a lot of reading of many different papers and have uncovered that there two types of broad spectrum kinases classified as:
Proline-directed kinases, such as CDK5 and GSK-3beta
Non-proline directed kinases

Source: https://www.hindawi.com/journals/omcl/2015/151979/

But I read in this paper: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3601591/

that Cdc2 can also phosphorylate tau

My new question is a follow up to my existing previous question, I guess why is tau phosphorylated at all? What causes tau to be phosphorylated at in the first place?
Thanks.

Comment: I recommend checking out PhosphoSitePlus's entry on [tau protein](https://www.phosphosite.org/proteinAction.action?id=1060&showAllSites=true). Click on the "Upstream" tab to see a list of confirmed (SRPK2, Syk) and putative kinases (PKA) and their associated phosphosites (i.e. the specific amino acid they phosphorylate). The [Wikipedia page for tau protein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tau_protein) also lists more kinases, as does [this 2013 review by Noble et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3696910/) As for *why* Tau protein is phosphorylated, [its phosphorylation is a key